# Is there a way to detect the audio input and set the bool to true when it detects it, otherwise it won't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, microphone

This is the code that takes audio from the microphone, I would also like it to set bool=true when it detects that the microphone delivers audio

I'll just point out that this should be consistent with unity

```
public void Record()
{
   string[] mic = new string[4];
    int i = 0; 
    foreach (var device in Microphone.devices)
    {
        i++;
        mic[i] =  device ;
        Debug.Log(mic[i]);
    }

    AudioSource audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(mic[1], true, 10, 44100);
    audioSource.Play();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Naudio to control and detect microphones and speakers.

just add Naudio nuget package and try using WaveIn and WaveOut for microphone and speakers respectively. and u can access them using

```
WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber)
```

and

```
WaveOut.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber)
```

see this [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/EnumerateOutputDevices.md)